# Gst-plugin-base building from source failure

Tags: linux, opencv, gstreamer, system-administration

I am a non-root user running cent-os linux, I had to install opencv on my remote machine...so I was installing it from source files...i.e in three steps:
`1../configure 2.make 3.make install ....`
I am facing this problem while installing gst-plugin-base... executing the make command I am getting this error...
I don`t know if it is due to some depedency missing or somethine else

```
error:
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_buffer_copy_deep'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `_gst_value_array_type'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_util_group_id_next'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_segment_position_from_running_time'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_buffer_list_copy_deep'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_event_parse_group_id'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_sample_set_buffer_list'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_segment_to_running_time_full'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_buffer_pool_config_validate_params'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `_gst_tag_list_type'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_event_set_group_id'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_message_set_group_id'
/global/home/bharat/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `gst_meta_api_type_get_tags'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [scrubby] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/global/home/bharat/opencv-tar/gst-plugins-base-1.0.0/tests/examples/seek'
make[3]: *** [seek] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/global/home/bharat/opencv-tar/gst-plugins-base-1.0.0/tests/examples'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/global/home/bharat/opencv-tar/gst-plugins-base-1.0.0/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/global/home/bharat/opencv-tar/gst-plugins-base-1.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to set dependancy on gstreamer core properly.. check this [faq](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-getting.html) .. the part regarding PKG_CONFIG_PATH .. if you want just to test few things you can use [gst-uninstalled](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/scripts/gst-uninstalled) - more info how to use it [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-developing.html)

Comment: @BharathVemula it must be upper case .. lower case won't work.. have you tried gst-uninstalled? or is it acceptable to go this way? if you find it difficult I can update answer with more info in how to do that :)

Comment: lol...i used it "pkg_config_path" in full caps...i know that.....what do u mean by gst-uninstalled?

Comment: @BharathVemula I randomly stumbled upon this [post](http://kacianka.at/?p=145) ..

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: @BharathVemula I guess it worked.. what was the problem in your case?

Comment: A dependency called "orc" was missing which was given in the link u sent me

Comment: hm the orc is not necessary.. only problem can be that you configure to use orc but you do not have it.. you could use --disable-orc or similar option to not use it.. orc is compile time optimisation